# Add new new line to the math mode

Tags: math-mode

I am trying to force adding a new line after `records with` in the math mode. How can I manage it in this case? I tried with `\n` without success.

```
\documentclass[
    english,
    german,
    11pt,
    twoside,
    a4paper,
    headsepline,
    footsepline
]{scrbook}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}


 After counting 6 records with the same stop\_name whereby 
 $behaviour\_id_{~records~ with~ the~ same~  stop\_name} > 
 behaviour\_id_{~min ~distance~ record}$, the speed average 
 of all these records is calculated. So in the case that the 
 speed average was less than 

\end{document}
```

Comment: You shouldn't do it like that.

Comment: A line cannot be broken in the middle of a subscript.

Comment: @Johannes_B: How else should I do it?

Comment: The options for `DIV` and `BCOR` are obsolete. Please remove them from your questions, or update your document. I don't want to add a comment to every single one of your questions.

Comment: @Johannes_B: Ok I have removed them but they dont cause the problem. How else should I do it?

Comment: `stop_name` is clearly some kind of keyword or variable, it should be written down as such. I don't know the context of your project, but wouldn't it be better to give clear and unique names instead of adding details in an index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula you want to write has only one feasible break point, after the `>` sign. There's no real way to print it inline, because as you'll see, it is about one line long; the only way I see is displaying it. Breaking in the middle of a subscript is definitely not an option, if you want that your readers understand what you're writing.

Note that a variable should always be typeset in the same way and that textual subscripts should be upright.

```
\documentclass[
    11pt,
    twoside,
    a4paper,
    headsepline,
    footsepline
]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\var}[1]{\textit{#1}}

\begin{document}

After counting 6 records with the same \var{stop\_name} whereby
\[
\var{behaviour\_id}_{\,\textup{records with the same \var{stop\_name}}} >
\var{behaviour\_id}_{\,\textup{min distance record}},
\]
the speed average of all these records is calculated. So in the case
that the speed average was less than

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Even though I would not advise you to do this, you can try `\substack` (included in `amsmath` package):

```
$behaviour\_id_{\substack{records~ with\\ the~ same~  stop\_name}} > 
behaviour\_id_{~min ~distance~ record}$
```

Comment: Why do you advise against using `\substack` and what woudl you recommend instead?

Comment: I object to breaking a subscript; if it is too long for single line, it shouldn't be a subscript. Of course, this does not include cases like the subscript of a sum, where one may write $i = 1$ with $i \ne j$.

I would revise the excerpt to something like: $behaviour\_id_{\rm ss} > behaviour\_id_{\rm min},$ where ss denotes the records with the same \var{stop_name}, and min the record having the minimum distance